# Logic error in menu and read functions to save and read to and from a file

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to call a read and write function from a menu, ask for inputs, save those inputs to a file then output the data to the screen. The menu works but I can only write to the file and save the data and exit. I cannot read or output what is saved to the file. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. I should have three working functions, main(), writeData(), and readData().

```
#include < iostream >
#include < fstream >
#include < string >
    using namespace std;

void menu(void);
void writeData(void);
void readData(void);
const char FileName[] = "TestAddress.txt";
string choice;

int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}
void menu(void)
{
    while (choice != "Q") {
        cout << "What would you like to do?\nA. Read the existing data:\nB. Write new data to the list:\nQ.Quit\n";
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == "A") {
            readData();
        }
        else if (choice == "B") {
            writeData();
        }
        else
            break;

    }
}

void writeData(void)
{
    ofstream outFile("testAddress.txt");
    string name;
    string street;
    string city;
    string state;
    int zip;
    string cont = "y";
    ifstream inFile;

    while (cont != "q") {
        cout << "Please enter the name:\n";
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "Please enter the street:\n";
        getline(cin, street);
        cout << "Please enter the city:\n";
        getline(cin, city);
        cout << "Please enter the state:\n";
        getline(cin, state);
        cout << "Please enter the zip code:\n";
        cin >> zip;
        outFile << name << street << "#" << city << state << zip << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Would you like to continue? Type q to quit:";
        getline(cin, cont);
        cin.ignore();
    }
    outFile.close();

    inFile.open("testAddress.txt");
    string fieldBuffer;
    if (inFile.is_open()) {
        while (inFile.eof()) {
            getline(inFile, fieldBuffer, ',');
            cout << fieldBuffer;
            cout << endl;

        }
    }
}
//use # sign for delimiter
void readData(void)
{
    ifstream inMyStream(FileName);
    if (inMyStream.is_open()) {
        string recBreaks = "";
        recBreaks.assign(20, '*');

        int fieldCount = 0;
        int recordCount = 1;

        fieldCount = 1;
        string fieldBuffer;
        getline(inMyStream, fieldBuffer, '#');

        while (inMyStream.eof()) {
            switch (fieldCount) {
                case 1:
                    cout << recBreaks << endl;
                    cout << "Record #" << recordCount << endl;
                    cout << "Name...." << fieldBuffer << endl;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "Street...." << fieldBuffer << endl;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "City...." << fieldBuffer << endl;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout << "State...." << endl;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cout << "Zip Code...." << endl;
                    fieldCount = 0;
                    recordCount++;
                    break;
                    getline(inMyStream, fieldBuffer, '#');
                    fieldCount++;
            }
            cout << recBreaks << endl;
            inMyStream.close();


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: why you cannot read from the file? There is a `void readData(void)`, what is wrong with it?

Comment: "_I cannot read or output what is saved to the file._" - Why? Compilation error? Did you add debug prints in the code or run it in a debugger?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: The `break; getline(...); fieldCount++;` part looks suspicious. When the program reaches the `break;`, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: The program compiles and runs, debugging doesn't flag anything.

Comment: Ted that part of the code was given to the class by the instructor... no wonder it doesn't work. Thanks for the input. I will look at changing that.

Comment: In writeData you open an output file `ofstream outFile("testAddress.txt");` and close the output file `outFile.close();` but where do you write any data to it?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed a number of errors in this code, THANX to all who commented! Everything is working now except the readData function. When I input data to the file and run the readData function I get an infinite loop. Is there a break statement out of place?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void menu(void);
void writeData(void);
void readData(void);
const char FileName[] = "TestAddress.txt";
string choice;

int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}
void menu(void)
{
    while (choice != "Q")
    {
        cout << "What would you like to do?\nA. Read the existing data:\nB. Write new data to the list:\nQ.Quit\n";
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == "A")
        {
            readData();
        }
        else if (choice == "B")
        {
            writeData();
        }
        else
            break;

    }
}

void writeData(void)
{
    ofstream outFile("TestAddress.txt");
    string name;
    string street;
    string city;
    string state;
    int zip;
    string cont = "y";
    ifstream inFile;

    while (cont != "q")
    {       
        cout << "Please enter the name:\n";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "Please enter the street:\n";
        getline(cin, street);
        cout << "Please enter the city:\n";
        getline(cin, city);
        cout << "Please enter the state:\n";
        getline(cin, state);
        cout << "Please enter the zip code:\n";
        cin >> zip;
        outFile << name<< "#" << street<< "#"<< city << "#" << state << "#" << zip << "#" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Would you like to continue? Type q to quit:";
        getline(cin, cont);
        cin.ignore();
    }
    outFile.close();

    inFile.open("TestAddress.txt");
    string fieldBuffer;
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        while (!inFile.eof())
        {
            getline(inFile, fieldBuffer, '#');
            cout << fieldBuffer;
            cout << endl;

        }
    }
}
//use # sign for delimiter
void readData(void)
{
    ifstream inMyStream(FileName);
    if (inMyStream.is_open())
    {
        string recBreaks = "";
        recBreaks.assign(20, '*');

        int fieldCount = 0;
        int recordCount = 1;

        fieldCount = 1;
        string fieldBuffer;
        getline(inMyStream, fieldBuffer, '#');

        while (!inMyStream.eof())
        {
            switch (fieldCount)
            {
            case 1:
                cout << recBreaks << endl;
                cout << "Record #" << recordCount << endl;
                cout << "Name...." << fieldBuffer << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Street...." << fieldBuffer << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "City...." << fieldBuffer << endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "State...." << fieldBuffer << endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "Zip Code...." << fieldBuffer << endl; 
                fieldCount = 0;
                recordCount++;
                break;

                getline(inMyStream, fieldBuffer, '#');
                fieldCount++;       
            }
            cout << recBreaks << endl;
            inMyStream.close();


        }

    }
}
```